# Password Validator , using hooks , states are not updating , Showing No error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, passwords, state

[Functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ6Aw.png) <-- image

In my program States are not changing

[Function Code For Vallidation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ6Aw.png)

```
    const checkPassword = (e) => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    Capital(password);
    Small(password);
    Numbers(password);
    Symbols(password);
    MinLen(password);
    console.log(ErrStatus.capital);
  };
```

here I have listed all variables
Which is used

```
  const capital = new RegExp("[A-Z]");
  const small = new RegExp("[a-z]");
  const number = new RegExp("[0-9]");
  const symbols = new RegExp("[@$!%#?&]");
  const minLen = new RegExp("[A-Za-zd@$!%*#?&]{8,}$");

  const ErrArr = {
    capital: "One capital Letter required",
    small: "One small Letter required",
    number: "One number Letter required",
    symbol: "One symbol  required",
    minLen: "min 8 character required",
  };
  const [ErrStatus, setErrStatus] = useState({
    capital: true,
    small: true,
    number: true,
    symbol: true,
    minLen: true,
  });
```

Refer The image for all the function
In my code 'ErrStatus' is not updating from my function (which is present in the image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the state into individual

```
  const [caps, setCaps] = useState(true);
  const [small, setSmall] = useState(true);
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(true);
  const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState(true);
  const [minLength, setMinLen] = useState(true);
```

It worked

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably about asynchronous javascript functions. The next check should run only after the previous one is finished.

So your code should look something like this:

```js
async function Capital(password){
  ...
  await setErrStatus({...ErrStatus, capital: false})
}
async function Small(password){
  ...
  await setErrStatus({...ErrStatus, small: false})
}
async function Numbers(password){
  ...
  await setErrStatus({...ErrStatus, numbers: false})
}
async function Symbols(password){
  ...
  await setErrStatus({...ErrStatus, symbols: false})
}
async function MinLen(password){
  ...
  await setErrStatus({...ErrStatus, minLen: false})
}
```

So you can call them this:

```js
const checkPassword = async (e) => {
  const password = e.target.value;
  await Capital(password);
  await Small(password);
  await Numbers(password);
  await Symbols(password);
  await MinLen(password);
  console.log(ErrStatus.capital);
};
```